# Searching data from one spreadsheet into another

Tags: excel, vba

I'm making a macro that is supposed to check for a set of values in an input list from the user. If the values from my source list are NOT in the user input, they have to be copied into a different spreadsheet. The macro runs without errors, but it won't filter any results. It just copies everything.
This is the code:

```
Sub CheckRow()
For i = 2 To Application.CountA(Worksheets("Source").Range("A:A")) 'Loop through rows
    Set rgFound = Worksheets("Input").Range("A:A").Find(Worksheets("Source").Range("A" & i).Value, LookAt:=xlWhole) 'Find the value from the source list in the Input List
If rgFound Is Nothing Then 'If there is no match it goes to output
    Worksheets("Output").Range("A" & Application.CountA(Worksheets("Output").Range("A:A")) + 1).Value = Worksheets("Source").Range("A" & i).Value 'Copy the value beow any existing values
End If
Next i
End Sub
```

I will appreciate any suggestions you have to offer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed. It seems that the Find method thinks that Value and ="Value" are two different things. Once I changed all the formula cells to plain text my code worked like a charm.

Answer (score 0):

Your condition should be `If Not rgFound Is Nothing Then` (the `Not` is missing in your code). Basically, the Find method doesn't find anything and therefore everything is copied.

I also advise you to use `Option Explicit` at the top of your code sheet. This would alert you to the use of the variable `j` in `Find(Worksheets("Source").Range("A" & j)`. I think you are looking for `A & i`. However, since j appears to have a value of 0 your code shouldn't copy anything because there is no row 0. Using `Option Explicit` would force you to declare all variables, eliminating guessing games like this one when reading your code. Since you are the one to read it most of the time you would also be the prime beneficiary of the improvement.

Comment: About the "j", my bad. I meant to change it to "i" to show here, because in my code this is nested inside another loop.